# React ApexCharts: Applying forecastDataPoints to a single series?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts in React to create a line chart with two series, representing 'Current Year' and 'Last Year' for direct comparison. The Y axis displays a percentage and the X axis runs 'Jan' to 'Dec', with monthly data points.

I am new to React and struggling to find how to apply the 'forecastDataPoints' property to just the 'Current Year' series. I can easily apply it to both series by using it within 'options' but this applies it to both series:

```
options: {
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'line',
  },
  colors: ['#172774','#F1B44C'],
  forecastDataPoints: {
    count: 3
  },
```

I assumed the way to achieve this is to put the forecastDataPoints property within the series, but this doesn't work:

```
this.state = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Curremt Year',
    data: [11, 24, 46, 62, 54, 52, 61, 67, 71, 78, 81, 83],
    forecastDataPoints: {
      count: 3
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Last Year',
    data: [5, 14, 12, 22, 25, 31, 39, 42, 45, 51, 52, 51],
  },
```

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

'forecastDataPoints' should be a level down from 'options'. It should be at the same level as 'chart' or 'xaxis'.

Ex:

```
this.state = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      id: "basic-bar"
    },
    forecastDataPoints: {
      count: 5
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "series-1",
      data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
    }
  ]
};
```

}

https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/forecastdatapoints/#